# Só grava o ID 0

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou com um problema que já tentei de muitas formas, mas o só está gravando o id Zero.

Parte do Botão de cadastrar a rua no bairro

Listagem dos bairros

bairro_lista.php

Parte do Botão de cadastrar a rua no bairro
Listagem dos bairros

```html
<?php
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) { ?>
<tr>
 <td><?php echo $linha['nome']; ?></td>
 <td class="actions " style="width: 38.66666667%;">
  <button type="button" name="addRua" id="<?php $linha['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addRua_data_Modal_rua" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs id_cod_bairro" >Cadastrar Rua</button>
 </td>
 
<?php } ?>
```

Parte do Modal onde seta os valores a serem gravados

```html
<div id="addRua_data_Modal_rua" class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static">  
  <div class="modal-dialog">  
    <div class="modal-content">  
   <div class="modal-header">  
     <!--<button name="fecharRua" id="fecharRua" type="submit" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  -->
     <input type="submit" name="fecharRua" id="fecharRua" value="&times;" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" />
     <!--<h4 class="modal-title" name="insert" id="insert" value="Adicionar" >Adicionar / Atualizar</h4>-->
     <label type="text" name="insert_title" id="insert_title" value="Cadastrar Bairro" class="modal-title" />  
   </div>  
   <div class="modal-body">  
     <form method="post" id="insert_form_rua">  
        <select name="tiporua" id="tiporua" class="form-control">  
         <option value="Rua">Rua</option>  
         <option value="Travessa">Travessa</option>  
         <option value="Avenida">Avenida</option>
       </select>  
      
       <br /> 
       <label>Digite o nome da Rua</label>        
       <input type="text" name="nome_rua" id="nome_rua" class="form-control" />       
       <br />  
       <input type="hidden" name="employee_id" id="employee_id" /> 
       <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-success" />
     </form> 
     
   </div>  
   <div class="modal-footer">  
     <input type="submit" name="fecharRua02" id="fecharRua02" value="Sair" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" />
   </div>  
    </div>  
  </div>  
</div>
```

Parte do javascript onde direciona para gravação

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
 $('#addRua').click(function(){  
 var id_cod_bairro = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#insert').val("Cadastrar");  
    $('#insert_title').val("Cadastrar Rua");
    

  }); 
  $('#insert_form_rua').on("submit", function(event){  
    event.preventDefault();  
    if($('#nome_rua').val() == "")  
    {  
   alert("nome is required");  
    }    
    else  
    {  
   $.ajax({  
     url:"insert_bairro_rua.php?id_usuario=<?php echo $_GET["id_usuario"]; ?>&cod_bairro=id_cod_bairro",  
     method:"POST",  
     data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
     data:$('#insert_form_rua').serialize(),      
     beforeSend:function(){  
       $('#insert').val("Inserindo Dados..."); 
       $('#insert_form_rua')[0].reset();
       
       
     },  
     success:function(data){  
       $('#addRua_data_Modal_rua').modal('hide');  
       $('#employee_table').html(data);
       $('#insert_form_rua')[0].reset();        
     }  
   }); 
   
    }  
  });
```

insert_bairro_rua.php

Onde grava os dados no Mysql

```html
 <?php  
 include("/lib/conexao.php");
 if(isset($_POST["employee_id"]))  
 {  
   $id_usuario = $_GET["id_usuario"]; 
   $cod_bairro = $_GET["cod_bairro"]; 
   $nome_rua = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome_rua', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
   $tiporua = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tiporua', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
   
   
      if($_POST["employee_id"] != '')  
      {  
  $query = "  
      UPDATE rua   
      SET   
      nome='$nome_rua',   
      tiporua='$tiporua',
      cod_bairro='$cod_bairro',
      id_usuario='$id_usuario'
      WHERE id='".$_POST["employee_id"]."'"
      ; 
  mysql_query($query,$conexao); 
      }  
      else  
      {  
  $query = "  
      INSERT INTO rua(nome, tiporua, cod_bairro, id_usuario)  
      VALUES('$nome_rua', '$tiporua','$cod_bairro','$id_usuario');
      "; 
  mysql_query($query,$conexao);     
        $message = 'Data Inserted';    
      }      
 }  
 ?>
```

Só tenho algumas noções destes códigos.

Comment: Provavelmente no seu banco de dados, você não setou sua chave primária como auto incremento

Comment: entendo, mas eu tenho um botão de ver as ruas do bairro e nas informações consegui ver o nome e ID do bairro e das ruas cadastradas nele. Se quiser ver como fiz, eu posto o código.

Answer (score 0):

No seu botão de cadastro no id está faltando a função `echo`

Errado:

```
id="<?php $linha['id']; ?>"
```

correto:

```
id="<?php echo $linha['id']; ?>"
```

Comment: Não deu certo, gravou o ultimo id, mas consegui através de um outro código.